# bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, shopify, liquid

I'm building a new shopify site. The issue is that sometimes I get the following error:

"bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4"

[Bootstrap Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpCKo.png)

The strange this is that this doesn't happen all the time, sometimes it throws the error and sometimes it doesn't. I'm using this version of Jquery https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js and it is being loaded before bootstrap. And I'm using bootstrap version 4.5.

This is a preview link to the theme I'm working on https://s51eqa94hdv9j0pu-12570887.shopifypreview.com.

I did some research and found that it may be that I'm loading another version of Jquery but I've looked everywhere in my code and I don't see one. I don't know that to do anymore, please help.

Below is the code from my theme.liquid file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    
  {% assign isDealer = false %}
  {% if customer.tags contains 'Tier 1 Wholesale' or customer.tags contains 'Tier 2 Wholesale' or customer.tags contains 'Tier 3 Wholesale' or customer.tags contains 'Tier 4 Wholesale' or customer.tags contains 'Custom 20% Wholesale' or customer.tags contains 'Custom 30% Wholesale' or customer.tags contains 'Custom 50% Wholesale' %}
    {% assign isDealer = true %}
  {% endif %}

  {% assign dealerPage = false %}
  {% if template contains 'dealers' or template contains 'wholesale-order-success' or template contains 'cart' or template contains 'easy-ordering' or template contains 'build-a-set' or template contains 'account' or template contains 'history' or template contains 'our-inks', or template contains 'history' or template contains 'artist-single' or template contains 'artists' or template contains 'premium-membership' or template contains 'videos' or template contains 'index' or template contains 'contact' %}
    {% assign dealerPage = true %}
  {% endif %}
    
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="MkB3TQan20jGaUftfaITby6KMe4klRMZ_fWsMYDTtCQ" />
    
<script>var redirectEU = 0;</script>
    
{% if canonical_url == "https://shop.intenzetattooink.com/pages/experience-premium-membership" or canonical_url == "https://shop.intenzetattooink.com/account/register" %}
    <script>redirectEU = 1;</script>
{% endif %}    
    
    
{% if canonical_url == 'https://shop.intenzetattooink.com/' or canonical_url == "https://shop.intenzetattooink.com/pages/experience-premium-membership" %}
<!-- Heatmap -->
<script>
  (function(h,e,a,t,m,p) {
  m=e.createElement(a);m.async=!0;m.src=t;
  p=e.getElementsByTagName(a)[0];p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p);
  })(window,document,'script','https://u.heatmap.it/log.js');
</script>
<!-- end Heatmap -->
{% endif %}    

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <style>.async-hide { opacity: 0 !important} </style>
    <script>(function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){s.className+=' '+y;h.start=1*new Date;
    h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
    (a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
    })(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,
    {'GTM-WJJF5KD':true});</script>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                              })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-875624-8', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Analytics -->

      <link rel="alternate" href="{{ shop.url }}" hreflang="en-us" />
    {% if shop.url contains "-eu" or shop.url contains ".eu" %}
        <link rel="alternate" href="{{ shop.url }}" hreflang="de-de" />
    {% else %}
        <link rel="alternate" href="{{ shop.url }}" hreflang="es-es" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="{{ shop.url }}" hreflang="de-de" />
    {% endif %}

    {% if current_tags %}{% assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' %}{% endif %}
    <title>
      {% if template contains "index" %}{{ page_title }}{% else %}{{ page_title }}{% if current_tags %} {{ 'general.meta.tagged_html' | t: tags: meta_tags }}{% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page_number: current_page }}{% endif %}{% unless page_title contains shop.name %} - {{ shop.name }}{% endunless %}{% endif %}
    </title>
    
    <!-- Cozy Country Redirect Script -->
    {{"https://cozycountryredirect.addons.business/js/eggbox/1234/dtag/script.js?shop=intenze-tattoo-ink.myshopify.com" | script_tag }}

    {% if page_description %}
      <meta name="description" content="{{ page_description | escape }}{% if current_tags %} {{ 'general.meta.tagged_html' | t: tags: meta_tags | escape }}.{% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page_number: current_page }}.{% endif %}" />
    {% endif %}

    {% include 'social-meta-info' %}

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="{{ settings.shop_bg_color }}">

    <!-- Bootstrap Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font-Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Slick Carousel CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>

    <!-- Icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ 'favicon.png' | asset_url }}">
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}" />

    <!-- Theme Stylesheet -->
    {{ 'theme.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var cspVariants = [];
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
      cspVariants.push('{{ variant.metafields.shappify_csp.csp_tag }}');
    {% endfor %}
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var pageTemplate = "";
  var shopURL = "{{ shop.url }}";
  pageTemplate = window.location.href;

  //console.log(pageTemplate);

</script>
   
{{ content_for_header }}    
   
<script>// <![CDATA[
  var isUsa = 0;
  var isEurope = 0;
  var isRussia = 0;
  var ip =  ''; //'178.18.25.255'; '95.31.18.119'; '173.249.9.82';
  var country_code = '';
  var currency_code = '';
  $.getJSON('//ipapi.co/'+ip+'/json/')
    .done(function(data) {
      var eu_country_codes = ['AX','AD','AL','AN','AM','AT','BA','BE','BG','BY','BV','CH','CY','CZ','DE','DK','EE','ES','FI','FO','FR','GE','GG','GI','GL','GR','GP','HR','HU','IE','IM','IS','IT','JE','LI','LT','LU','LV','MC','MD','ME','MK','MT','NL','NO','PL','PT','RE','RO','SE','SI','SJ','SK','SM','TR','UA','UK','VA','XK','YU'];
      var ru_country_codes = ['RU'];
      var us_country_codes = ['US','SA'];
      ip = data.ip;
      //data.country = 'BE';
      //data.country_name = 'Belerus';
      //data.currency = 'EUR';
      country_code = data.country;
      currency_code = data.currency;
      console.log("country: " + country_code);
      console.log("currency: " + currency_code);
      if (eu_country_codes.indexOf(data.country) !== -1) {
        isUsa = 0;
        isRussia = 0;
        isEurope = 1;
        if (redirectEU == 1) {
          window.location.replace("http://www.intenzeproducts.eu/intenze-subscribers/");
        }else if (popupEU == 1) {
          $('.country_name').html(data.country_name);
          $.fancybox.open($('#eu_message'));
        }
      }else if (us_country_codes.indexOf(data.country) !== -1) {
        isEurope = 0;
        isRussia = 0;
        isUsa = 1;
      }else if (ru_country_codes.indexOf(data.country) !== -1) {
        isUsa = 0;
        isEurope = 0;
        isRussia = 1;
        if(popupRU == 1){
          $.fancybox.open($('#ru_message'));
        }
      }
      console.log("isUsa: " + isUsa);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        isUsa = 1;
        country_code = 'US';
        currency_code = 'USD';
    });  
  
  
// ]]></script>

{% if template == 'page.nofollownoindex' or template == 'page.member-landing' or template == 'page.videos' %}
     <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
{% else %}
     <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
{% endif %}      

</head>

<body class="{{ template | replace: '.', ' ' | truncatewords: 1, '' | handle }}">

<!-- Bold: Memberships -->
{% if customer %}
<div class="bold_customer_id" hidden>{{ customer.id }}</div>
{% endif %}
<!-- end Bold code -->

<!-- Membership Pop Up -->
{% include 'membership-signup-form' %}
<!-- End Membership Pop Up -->

    
    {% if isDealer and dealerPage %}
        {% include 'wholesale-header' %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'retail-header' %}
  {% endif %}

      {% unless template contains "index" %}
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      {% endunless %}

      {% if isDealer %}
          {% if dealerPage %}
              {{ content_for_layout }}
          {% else %}
              {% include 'wholesale-redirect' %}
          {% endif %}
      {% elsif template contains 'easy-ordering'  %}
          {% include 'wholesale-note' %}
      {% else %}
          {{ content_for_layout }}
      {% endif %}

      </div> <!-- end container -->


    {% if isDealer and dealerPage %}
        {% include 'wholesale-footer' %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'retail-footer' %}
    {% endif %}
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      adroll_adv_id = "AXKWHKTRSRAWHD4Q75HHJZ";
      adroll_pix_id = "NRMNVQNOYFB3PJV7NY4UKS";
      /* OPTIONAL: provide email to improve user identification */
      /* adroll_email = "username@example.com"; */
      (function () {
          var _onload = function(){
              if (document.readyState && !/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)){setTimeout(_onload, 10);return}
              if (!window.__adroll_loaded){__adroll_loaded=true;setTimeout(_onload, 50);return}
              var scr = document.createElement("script");
              var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://s.adroll.com" : "http://a.adroll.com");
              scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
              scr.type = "text/javascript";
              scr.src = host + "/j/roundtrip.js";
              ((document.getElementsByTagName('head') || [null])[0] ||
                  document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode).appendChild(scr);
          };
          if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('load', _onload, false);}
          else {window.attachEvent('onload', _onload)}
      }());
  </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS, Popper.js -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Slick Carousel JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

    <script src="{{ 'application.js' | asset_url }}"></script>

    {% include 'smile-initializer' %}
    <script async type="text/javascript" data-api-key="" id="stamped-script-widget" src="https://cdn-stamped-io.azureedge.net/files/widget.min.js"></script>

</body>

<script>
  $(window).on("load",function(){
    {% if customer.tags contains 'subscriber-tier' or customer.tags contains 'subscriber-tier-90' or customer.tags contains 'subscriber-tier-re' %}
    $('.btn_footer').click(function(){
      SweetTooth.createActivity({ activity_type: 'activity_WICnbkVZVkthrCJIMxi8MwLR' })
        .then(function(activity) {
          // Success
        console.log('Smile: Created activity ' + activity.id);
        }).catch(function(err) {
          // Failure
        console.log('Smile: Something went wrong.');
        });

    });
    {% endif %}
  });
</script>  

<!-- Jotform Account Information Update Request Form -->
<script src ="https://form.jotform.com/static/feedback2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var JFL_200894233311043 = new JotformFeedback({
    formId: '200894233311043',
    base: 'https://form.jotform.com/',
    windowTitle: 'Update Account Information Request',
    background: '#eb3587',
    fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    type: 'false',
    height: 500,
    width: 700,
    openOnLoad: false
  });
</script>  
    
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .sticky-top {
      position:fixed !important;
      top:0 !important;
      z-index:9998 !important;
      width: 100%;
      height: 54px;      
    }    
    .sweettooth-launcher-container,.stamped-widget-drawer {
      z-index: 1000 !important;
    }
  }

  /* DB 10/2018 */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    div.stamped-widget-drawer {
        right: auto !important;
        left: -300px !important;
    }    
    .stamped-widget-drawer div.stamped-widget-button {
        width: 115px !important;
        margin-right: -115px;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
        left: auto !important;
        right: 0 !important;
    }
  }

  {% if isDealer %}
    .sweettooth-launcher-container.sweettooth-show, .smile-launcher-frame-container,#stamped-reviews-widget {
      display: none;
    }
  {% endif %}
</style>
     
    
</html>
```

Comment: make sure your jQuery `script` is above the bootstrap cdn links you have in your `head`

Comment: Show us how are you loading these assets in the code. That should help clarify things.

Comment: I'm loading Jquery script before bootstrap but I'm still getting the error. I added my code above. Thanks in advance for your help.